# Track visitor use of "Ctrl + F" on a website?

Tags: seo, tracking, analytics, click-tracking

Would it theoretically be possible to detect (e.g. via JavaScript) if a user queries a webpage with the Windows shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, or the Mac-equivalent <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in their browser?

The first step would be to detect whether that function was called, but it'd be a different ball game to track their keystrokes...

I'm asking because a lot of the time, web apps seem to re-wire keyboard shortcuts to do other things (or they get disabled completely, for example, in some cases of HTML5 `canvas`, the shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close the tab doesn't work). This is likely a different mechanism, and I don't have high hopes. Furthermore, [only about 10% of users](http://blog.mozilla.org/metrics/2011/08/25/do-90-of-people-not-use-ctrlf/) know how to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> function anyway.

Comment: "only 10%" - flabbergasted!

Comment: @w3d, what are you saying?

Comment: Just expressing my surprise that "only about 10% of users [reportedly] know how to use Ctrl+F". (flabbergasted - "As if struck dumb with astonishment and surprise")

Comment: No sarcasm intended? ;)

Comment: I wasn't intending sarcasm, although admittedly I do find that statistic rather hard to swallow! :)

Comment: @Baumr, What? You mean you ain't surprised only 10% of people know how to do CtrlF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want capture the event keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and continue with the opening of the standard searchbox of the browser, you could do this:

```
var KEY_CTRL = 17;
var KEY_f = 70;

var isReserved = false;
var useExclusiveKeyEvent = false;
var isNewSearchEvent = false;


/*THIS VARIABLE IS RENDERED BY SERVER SIDE*/
var clientRandomKey = "78349DE472AA30032DE2DF344FF28374";

window.onkeyup=function(ev){
  if(ev.which == KEY_CTRL){
    isReserved=false;
  }
}
window.onkeydown=function(ev){
  //!IMPORTANT NOT MAKE UI DELAY IN THIS FUCTION
  if(ev.which == KEY_CTRL) {
       isReserved=true;
  }
    if((isReserved==true)&&(ev.which == KEY_f)) {       
    var currentDate = new Date();
    console.log( "INTO EVENT FUNCTION >\n   "+ currentDate+ " \n   ID: "+clientRandomKey+"\n   launch search a word");
    isNewSearchEvent=true;
    if(useExclusiveKeyEvent){
      return false;}
    }
}

window.setInterval(function(){            
    if(isNewSearchEvent){
      isNewSearchEvent=false;
      //TODO ajax send code
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var msg = "OUTSIDE EVENT FUNCTION >\n   " + currentDate+ " \n   ID: "+clientRandomKey+"\n   launch search a word"
      console.log(msg);
      alert(msg);
    }
},2500);
```

[This is a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/XuxkR/73/).

As you can see in the example, when the user presses the right keyboard combination, event function sends a `"log string"` in the console ("EVENT INTO FUNCTION"),
while changing the state of a flag(`isNewSearchEvent`).

This flag is evaluated in a timer to send another `"log string"` in the console ("OUTSIDE EVENT FUNCTION")

and open an alert with the same message.

[image: log console]

This double passage is necessary because cannot  create breaks into the event function, that should listen in a correct speed of capture.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Very interesting. So after this, would it be possible to track keystrokes?

Comment: Sure,is a correct interpretation of the real possibilities

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ctrl = false;
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.which == 17){
      ctrl = true;
    }
    if(e.which == 70 && ctrl == true){
      e.preventDefault();

    }
  }, true);

  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.which == 17){
      ctrl = false;

    }
  });
});
```

And with `.preventDefault()` we cancel the regular event.
But for the Command key I'm not sure what it is, some says that its `e.metaKey` if you are using jQuery, because the problem is that the Command key don't have the same JavaScript key code on each browser, so you must handle it manually or jQuery can help you.

If you want to test it http://jsfiddle.net/a5t2q/

EDIT : You must click on the "Result" section to see that Ctrl+F is blocked, because that section is the one referred as "document" in this case.